# How to validate QuickBooks's connection?

Tags: c#, quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I have been integrating QuickBooks's API to my web application. I made requests to get tokens (both request token and secret token), I stored them to database. So, how can I validate connection at second time or more, I mean because I had tokens in database, so I don't want to re-authorize to get other new tokens. I tried to find solutions to resolve it, but there's no anything. Please give me some methods or advices to get it done. Thank you very much!

Comment: can you please explain more with your code....

Answer (score 1):

> So, how can I validate connection at second time or more,

You can validate tokens by doing a query against a v3 service, and checking to see if you get a `200 OK` or a `401 Unauthorized` response back.

Pseudo-code should look something like this:

```
function am_i_connected_to_quickbooks()
{
   if (you have tokens stored in your database)
   {
       results = do_qb_query("SELECT * FROM Customer MAXRESULTS 1")
       if (you got a 200 OK back from Intuit)
       {
           // You are connected, and the tokens are still valid/have not been revoked
           return true
       }
   }

   // You don't have tokens, or your tokens are invalid (revoked, expired, incorrect, etc.)
   return false
}
```